# How can I shutdown CompletionService

Tags: java, java.util.concurrent

I need to do something like this:

```
ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2);
CompletionService<Boolean> completionService = new ExecutorCompletionService<>(executor);
int i = 0;
while (i < 40) {
  completionService.submit(getTask());
  i++;
}
executor.shutdown();
System.out.println("SHUTDOWN");
```

But after calling `shutdown` on `executor` object `completionService` still execute tasks.

How can I make it stop?

Is there are any way to stop ExecutorService but wait for the completion of currently executing tasks?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `ExecutorService` will carry on executing tasks *already submitted* but will not allow further tasks to be submitted, from the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#shutdown--)

> Initiates an orderly shutdown in which **previously submitted tasks are executed**, but no new tasks will be accepted. Invocation has no additional effect if already shut down.
>   <sub>emphasis mine</sub>

So you have already submitted 40 tasks, these will be executed before shutdown.

If you want to force shutdown. You can use [`shutdownNow`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#shutdownNow--):

> Attempts to stop all actively executing tasks, **halts the processing of waiting tasks**, and returns a list of the tasks that were awaiting execution.
>   <sub>emphasis mine</sub>

Which will abandon scheduled tasks, as you want.

N.B.: Stopping tasks *in progress* is another issue entirely.

Comment: Thank you! Is there are any way to stop ExecutorService but wait for completion currently executed tasks?

Comment: @Kirill call [`ExecutorService.awaitTermination`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#awaitTermination-long-java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit-) after calling one of the shutdown methods.

Comment: it looks like as what I need, but when I use it like this:
    `executor.shutdown();
    executor.awaitTermination(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);`
my tasks doesn't stop execution. When I call it after `executor.shutdownNow();` tasks are interrupted immediately without waiting for end executing.

Comment: @Kirill that's then your tasks' problem. Either you need to use `shutdown` and wait for all tasks to complete, or you need to use `shutdownNow` and more your tasks uninterruptible...

Comment: What problem with task? I don't understand. Is there are no way to wait currently executed tasks to complete and don't execute others?

Answer (score 2):

Use `shutdownNow()` which will **try to stop** already executing task. Read this https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#shutdownNow()

The shutdown of already executing task is an attempt only but will not be guaranteed to stop.

The `shutdown()` method only stops taking new tasks but already executing task will continue to execute.

---

UPDATE for the "Is there are any way to stop ExecutorService but waiting for completion currently executed tasks?"

One option I can think of is this -

The `completionService.submit(getTask());` return object of type `Future`. You can write code to check if the task `isDone()`. After calling `shutdownNow()` you can check the tasks in a loop for `isDone()`. You need to store the tasks in list when returned by submit method.

Comment: This isn't entirely true - `shutdownNow` will abandon already _scheduled_ tasks and will **interrupt** already _executing_ tasks. Whether they stop or not is entirely up to the task and whether it pays attention to the interrupt.

Comment: I did not say it will shut down 100%. I said it will try to shutdown. In bold now.

Comment: I think you need to make the distinction between **new**, **scheduled** and **executing** tasks.

Comment: Why not use the purpose built method to wait for it to finish?

Comment: Yes that is a better option

Comment: I think while I checking task `isDone` some other task can start executing

Comment: Since you have already called shutdownNow new tasks will not execute. It has tried its best to shutdown already executing task. So you are not just waiting for the already running tasks to finish (complete, canelled or interrupted).